# Feasibility of Machine Learning techniques for Network Intrusion Detection

Tags: matlab, networking, pattern-matching, machine-learning, neural-network

Is there a machine learning concept (algorithm or multi-classifier system) that can detect the variance of network attacks(or try to).

One of the biggest problems for signature based intrusion detection systems is the inability to detect new or variant attacks.

Reading up, anomaly detection seems to still be a statistical based en-devour it refers to detecting patterns in a given data set which isn't the same as detecting variation in packet payloads. Anomaly based NIDS monitors network traffic and compares it against an established baseline of a normal traffic profile. The baseline characterizes what is "normal" for the network - such as the normal bandwidth usage, the common protocols used, correct combinations of ports numbers and devices etc

Say some one uses Virus A to propagate through a network then some one writes a rule to stop Virus A but another person writes a "variation" of Virus A called Virus B purely for the purposes of evading that initial rule but still using most if not all of the same tactics/code. Is there not a way to detect variance?

If there is whats the umbrella term it would come under, as ive been under the illusion that anomaly detection was it.

Could machine learning be used for pattern recognition(rather than pattern matching) at the packet payload level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think your intution to look at machine learning techniques is correct, or will turn out to be correct (*One of the biggest problems for signature based intrusion detection systems is the inability to detect new or variant attacks*.) The superior performance of ML techiques is in general due to the ability of these algorithms to *generalize* (a multiplicity of *soft constraints* rather than a few hard constraints). and to *adapt* (updates based on new training instances to frustrate simple countermeasures)--two attributes that i would imagine are crucial for identifying network attacks.

The theoretical promise aside, there are practical difficulties with applying ML techniques to problems like the one recited in the OP. By far the most significant is the *difficultly in gathering data to train the classifier*. In particular, reliably labeling data points as "intrusion" is probably not easy; likewise, my guess is that these instances are sparsely distributed in the raw data."

I suppose it's this limitation that has led to the increased interest (as evidenced at least by the published literature) in applying ***unsupervised*** ML techniques to problems like network intrusion detection.

Unsupervised techniques differ from supervised techniques in that the data is fed to the algorithms without a response variable (i.e., without the class labels). In these cases you are relying on the algorithm to discern structure in the data--i.e., some inherent ordering in the data into reasonably stable groups or clusters (possibly what you the OP had in mind by "variance." So with an unsupervised technique, there is no need to explicitly show the algorithm instances of each class, nor is it necessary to establish baseline measurements, etc.

The most frequently used unsupervised ML technique applied to problems of this type is probably the ***Kohonen Map*** (also sometimes called ***self-organizing map*** or ***SOM***.)

i use Kohonen Maps frequently, but so far not for this purpose. There are however, numerous published reports of their successful application in your domain of interest, e.g.,

[Dynamic Intrusion Detection Using Self-Organizing Maps](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.61.5644)

[Multiple Self-Organizing Maps for Intrusion Detection](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.10.9322)

I know MATLAB has at least one available implementation of Kohonen Map--the [SOM Toolbox](http://www.cis.hut.fi/somtoolbox/). The homepage for this Toolbox also contains a brief introduction to Kohonen Maps.